# scipy minimize with method SLSQP returns success on an infeasible program

Tags: python, scipy, minimization

While solving the trust region subproblem described below `minimize` returns with success, although the program is infeasible.

```
from numpy import array
from numpy import dot
from numpy import reshape
from numpy import zeros
from numpy.linalg import norm
from scipy.optimize import minimize


cIneq = array([ 9.])
AIneq = array([[ 1., -1.]])

cEq = array([ 0.09070257])
AEq = array([[ 1.00427046,  0.35586232]])

radius = 1

cons = [
    {'type': 'ineq',
        'fun': lambda n: radius**2 - dot(n, n),
        'jac': lambda n: reshape(-2*n, (1,2))},
    {'type': 'ineq',
        'fun': lambda n: -cIneq - dot(AIneq, n),
        'jac': lambda n: -AIneq},
    {'type': 'eq',
        'fun': lambda n: cEq + dot(AEq, n),
        'jac': lambda n: AEq}]


res = minimize(lambda n: dot(n, n), jac=lambda n: reshape(2 * n, (1,2)), x0=zeros(2),
                constraints=cons, method='SLSQP', options={"disp": False, "maxiter": 1000}, tol=1e-8)

print(radius**2 - dot(res.x, res.x)) # -11.5640205848
print(res.success) # True
```

Currently, the only work-around I know is to add a double check after running `minimize`:

```
def dbl_check_sol(cons, res):
    if not res.success:
        return True
    for c in cons:
        if c['type'] == 'ineq':
            if (c['fun'](res.x) < -1e-8).any():
                return False
        elif c['type'] == 'eq':
            if norm(c['fun'](res.x)) > 1e-8:
                return False
        else:
            raise Exception('unknown type of constraint')
    return True

print(dbl_check_sol(cons, res)) # False
print(res) # I see no other errors, and the message is 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
```

What am I doing wrong here? At first, I thought that it might be an issue with the dimensions, but the same result happens if I do not reshape the jacobian of the trust region problem, and just say `'jac': lambda n: return -2*n},`.